# Android Volley HTTPS Headers throws 400

Tags: android, android-volley

My app is already been running for a while now and all worked really good!
The server updated recently from http to https,
ever since that change I get Error 400 BAD INPUT on every server call.
After researching the matter for some painful hours I found out that if I send a request with empty headers the request PASS! with no errors.
But I need those headers!

Also, in both iOS and in my checks in POSTMAN, the headers are going in well so the problem must be in the client I think.

I'm sending my headers Overriding the getHeaders method.

Anyone had this problem before?
Any idea how to fix this?

My code for the headers:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8");
    headers.put("AppVersion", BaseApplication.getCurrentDevice().getAppVersion());
    headers.put("DeviceType", BaseApplication.getCurrentDevice().getDeviceType().toString());
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: add only  `application/json`

Comment: already tried that, still getting 400 error. =\

Comment: try to add `Rest Client Extension` in Firefox or chrome and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so for anyone that has this problem, here is an explanation.

I further investigated my issue and found out that my problem at the end was not the headers!

I tried to narrow it down and found out that it only gives me 400 error on POST requests with Body.
apparently after changing to HTTPS volley is sending empty bodies.
and I didn't understood why.

at the end I found my problem.
in the headers, I needed to add "charset=utf-8"
and yes, in the above code I do have charset, 
but i wrote "utf8", and apparently in HTTPS it needs "utf-8"!!
that little " - " made all the difference!

again, my app working without that "-" for 3 months already and no problems, for some reason after changing to HTTPS the utf8 needs to change to "utf-8" !

hope that will help someone.

you can find more details regarding this problem in this link:

http://envyandroid.com/android-volley-empty-parameters/

JozeRi